# SAS EG: including local file while running on server

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

How can I use include statement to reference local file when I'm connected to server?
When I run the code I get an error saying that there is no such file on the server.
How do I tell EG to look for file locally?

I have ways to get around that, like telling the code to run on 'local' server and then
I copy results over. Or I just add the code I need as a Code node in EG.
Both of those are not very practical when working with old code that uses include heavily.

Comment: How have you done it in the past? Do you have SAS installed locally? You could start locally then REMOTE CONNECT to the server and UPLOAD your results. Identify your current setup....

Comment: I do have SAS installed so that should work. But is there a way to do it from EG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Enterprise Guide, programs (code nodes) have an option to choose the environment. Choose LOCAL for the program that executes the %INCLUDE for the local program. Then you need to move the resulting data set(s) to the remote server via SAS/CONNECT (RSUBMIT) and put them in a permanent location. The subsequent programs can have your remote server chosen as the environment and will be able to act on the data you previously moved up the remote server.

If this seems plausible...I can expand the answer

Comment: If you mean `Right click code node -> Select server`, that's what I'm doing now. I was hoping to avoid moving the data over to server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to reference local SAS data sets (sas7bdat files), you can use the Tasks->Data->Upload Data Files to Server task.  This will capture the step of copying your data set files to the SAS workspace as part of your process flow.